# Make table cells resizable in all directions

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I need to make table cells resizable in all directions (vertically and horizontally). Seems like using `jQuery UI resizable` widget almost does the job:

```
$('.table td').resizable();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vUv8U/1/)

But not exactly... I got a problem with downsizing elements in same row / column, where other element in same row / column is bigger. For example, when you set upper left one to width 100px and then try to set lower-left element to 50px, it simply doesn't downsize, because there is wider element in same column.

Any ideas how to manage that?

I tried different approaches, like setting td style to `display:inline-block` or `display:block` with `float:left`, but it is getting even worse that way.

Comment: Perhaps setting "overflow: hidden" or "overflow: scroll" on the table cells' CSS?  That might allow for making columns more narrow

Comment: in Table column size will remain same across all rows, that is why you requirement is not working, rather you can use divs or Steve Wellens's answer

Comment: @Zainul Abedin: But I did use div :-) Please check attached fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have better luck making the divs inside the tds re-sizable:

```
$('.table td div').resizable();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Steve_Wellens/vUv8U/2/)

Comment: This is totally not what I want. Div has to be always 100% width and 100% height. Free space in table cell is unacceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution:

```
$('.table td').resizable({
    resize: function(event,ui) {
        var col = $(this).index()+1;
        $(this).closest('table').find('tr td:nth-child('+col+')').width(ui.size.width);
        $(this).parent().find('td').height(ui.size.height);
    }
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/vUv8U/3/)

Comment: But there seems to be another problem. When table width is more than screen, it cuts some inner divs... doesn't allow table to be more than 100%.